# qfrm module - No module named 'qfrm.Options' (Python 3.5.1)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am quite newbie in python and I am trying to make the qfrm 0.2.0.27 library to work. Unfortunately there is no documentation about this library. I installed it using pip and when I try to import it I get the following error:

No module named 'qfrm.Options'

Does anyone have a solutions for this? I am using python 3.5.1. and PyCharm

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qfrm/0.1.1.12. Have you installed `pandas`?

Comment: Yes absolutely. In fact, I forgot to mention that I am talking about the version 0.2.0.27 (I edited the original post). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem.  The current version in the PyPi index is qfrm-0.2.0.27.

The version on the website appears to be qfrm-0.2.0.23.  Although it is older, it worked without error for me.

If you download the ...23 whl file and install that one (pip install [file_name].whl) you may find it works better.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Python version 2.7.11 and was **unable** to install qfrm version 0.2.0.27 and received the error message: `No module named 'qfrm.Options'`

However, I **was able** to install qfrm version 0.2.0.23, as follows:  `pip install -v qfrm==0.2.0.23`